# Cannot remove account reference in NXOauth2Client

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use NXOauth2Client to login and logout Instagram API, the first time I run and login, it shows the login fields from Instagram, but later I cannot logout to test with another Instagram account. Even I did remove all account from NXOAuth2AccountStore

this is my login

```
- (IBAction)Login:(id)sender {

    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]requestAccessToAccountWithType:@"Instagram"];
}
```

and this is logout

```
- (IBAction)Logout:(id)sender {    
for (NXOAuth2Account *account in [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] accounts]) {
    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] removeAccount:account];
}
}
```

I would be appreciated for any help